Is there anything illegal about dumping a wild animal carcass in Central Park?
Related to a certain confession, statute of limitations might have kicked in, but is anything illegal (such as littering, for example) about dumping a wild animal's carcass in Central Park?

Given that the confession involved a car, I'd suggest that this page about illegal dumping from the NYC Sanitation department might be a starting point:

Illegal Dumping
It's ILLEGAL to dispose of any type of material or debris by vehicle
and dump it on any street, lot, park, public space – public or
private.

But there is also this

Litter
It's illegal to leave trash on the sidewalk, in the street, or any
other public space, or to throw it out building windows or vehicles.


I would not be surprised if the definition of "trash" under the littering law excludes dead animals (nor would I be surprised if it includes them).

@phoog why would it exclude dead animals? If I throw a dead racoon out the window of my car I'm still likely getting a ticket.

@ChellCPlus whether it excludes dead animals depends on the text of the definition.  I don't know what the text is, but it could easily be too specific to include animal carcasses.

@phoog The link in this answer contains a definition of litter that specifically includes "carcasses of dead animals". Of course, definitions can differ by jurisdiction, but I expect it's typical.

This seems to be a pretty clear violation of NY game laws.
from https://www.law.cornell.edu/regulations/new-york/6-NYCRR-1.31#:~:text=Any%20person%20who%20takes%20a%20bear%20must%20report%20as%20specified,outside%20any%20type%20of%20vehicle.

(1) Any person who takes a bear must immediately fill out completely,
using indelible ink, the bear carcass tag and cut out or mark with
indelible ink the month and date of kill where printed along the edge
of the carcass tag. The taker must also attach the bear carcass tag
securely to the bear, except that the tag does not need to be attached
while the bear is being dragged or physically carried by the taker to
a camp or point where other transportation is available. It is
unlawful for any person to remove the tag until the bear is prepared
for consumption. Any person who takes a bear must report as specified
in section 180.10 of this Title.


(2) It is unlawful for any person to
transport or possess a bear without the bear tag attached to it. The
carcass of a bear can be transported inside or outside any type of
vehicle.

Not a lawyer, but I am a hunter in NY.  I would have to look up exactly what it means to "take a bear" to see if that part applies -- I don't know if picking up roadkill counts.  I suspect it doesn't, as the bear was found dead.
Transporting a bear without a tag, though, is not legal in NY regardless of how the bear was taken or found.
When RFK related the story, he said that he could have gotten a tag.  He never said that he did get a tag.  I don't believe that he did.  If he did, it would have been unlawful to remove it when he dropped it off in Central Park.  The bear was found without tags, or it wouldn't have caused a mystery when it was found.  Presumably, it was never tagged, or the tag was removed.  If it was never tagged, that would be on RFK.  I suppose it's possible that somebody encountered the bear in the park and removed the tag.  In any case, game laws were clearly broken, but exactly how they were broken and by who might require some investigation.
So that's at least some of the relevant laws, but there's also the laws of nature, where messing with bear cubs is sort of like Russian Roulette, risking an encounter with mama bear.

I think it's clear that he never got a tag. According to his recounting of the day, he skipped lots of steps because he was under time pressure.

"Transporting a bear without a tag, though, is not legal in NY regardless of how the bear was taken or found." What if you're driving to the office to purchase the tag? A hunter would obviously get the tags beforehand, but that's not likely if you find roadkill by accident.

@Barmer -- you don't drive to the office to purchase a tag.  Tags come with your hunting license.  Roadkills are tagged by officers on the scene.  The right way to have done this during this century would have been to call a conservation officer or state troopers, either of which can write out a tag on the spot, for free.  In this case, they very well might have said no, because of the mama bear danger.  If this were easy, it would encourage illegal trophy seeking, with everybody with a bear in the car saying "I found it on the road".

I guess you can tell I know nothing about hunting....

@Barmar  -- I have a wonderful story about a friend who picked up a fresh roadkill deer in Ohio, tagged by an officer at the scene.  When he knicked a part he shouldn't have while trying to gut out the animal, he went and knocked on his neighbor's door, covered in blood, saying "I need a hose, right now".

@ScottSeidman: Would I be correct in assume the term "transport" would simply not apply to someone who moves a carcass that would be an obstacle to traffic to the nearest practical location that would not be an obstacle, and a tag would only be required if e.g. someone wanted to salvage whatever parts of a road-kill carcass could be useful?

@supercat  -- I believe, but I'm not certain, that "transport" would mean a vehicle, and that most officers (Conservation Officer or otherwise) are reasonable.     Freezers at home, though, certainly go toward "possess".  CO's can get snippy, though.  I saw a CO send an ice fisherman back to his truck to get his license.  He was pretty rude to her, and while he was at his truck, she wrote him up for leaving his fishing line in the water unattended!  Keep in mind, much conservation law like this is to discourage poaching, and to limit excuses available to poachers.

@supercat -- the first paragraph concerning tagging actually says "... except that the tag does not need to be attached while the bear is being dragged or physically carried by the taker to a camp or point where other transportation is available", so I think that includes the exception you describe.

@ScottSeidman: That doesn't seem to apply.  One, it only applies to the "taker", which the person clearing the road is not.  Two, clearing the road isn't carrying the bear to either a camp or onward transportation.
